# Static Rigidbody 2D or just Collider 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at Unity. As far as I know, it's a **Static Rigidbody 2D** is designed to not move under simulation at all like ground, walls...

However, in my game, I only push a **Box Collider 2D** component to the game object wall. That game object perfectly acts as a wall when other rigid body interacts with it.

Should I add a Rigidbody 2D component with static body type to my wall?  If i do that, will the performance be better?

Comment: Yes why not? I think you should have done yourself before asking here. your question does not meet stackoverflow guidelines(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I suggest you to remove question, try that yourself and if something won't work then ask it here

Comment: Sorry @Chestera , Looks like you misunderstood me. I confuse if I add Static Rigidbody 2D to my game object that will reduce some physic calculation?

Comment: If you mean efficiency, yes, for static objects it's better to use static rigidbody for performance

Comment: @TiếnThànhNguyễn What Chestera is saying is false. Rigidbodies are the component to simulate physics or to sync physics interactions with moving objects. If your objects (ie walls) don't move, keep them with a collider only, and mark the object as 'static'. --- When talking about unnecessary components generally. More components = more processing required = less efficient. Only add what you will need, and only keep enabled what you are currently using, unless the overhead from enabling/disabling is greater than enabled full time; which you will only see in the profiler.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Are you sure you want to use that language?

Answer (score 0):

Objectively speaking - no. If your code works, then adding a rigidbody only means that unity has to execute more code for that gameobject.

Technically speaking, the gameObject you are moving should have a dynamic (If it is affected by physics) or kinematic rigidbody2D. This will help it can interact with other colliders, while the wall can just be a regular box Collider2D.

But honestly, performance probably shouldn't be your first concern - whether you add a static rigidbody to the wall will be negligible in the greater scheme of things.